# Trouble creating users with iRedmail

Tags: python, email-client

I am trying to create a list of 10k users on a new email sever I set up using iRedmail. However I tried to use their Python script to generate the email addresses and I keep getting the following error:

```
  File "iRedMail-0.9.2/tools/create_mail_user_OpenLDAP.py", line 286, in <module>
domain, username, passwd, cn, quota, groups = re.split('\s?,\s?', entry)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This is the layout of the data I am trying to upload:

```
domain.com,first.last,password,First Last,,
domain.com,first.last,password,First Last,,
```

The are it's throwing the error is here:

```
for entry in userList.readlines():
entry = entry.rstrip()
domain, username, passwd, cn, quota, groups = re.split('\s?,\s?', entry)
dn, data = ldif_mailuser(domain, username, passwd, cn, quota, groups)

# Write LDIF data.
result = open(ldif_file, 'a')
ldif_writer = ldif.LDIFWriter(result)
ldif_writer.unparse(dn, data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the original csv I was using (it created weird line breaks instead of the normal ).